# How can I use cypress to make a JSON call?

Tags: json, cypress

Day one with Cypress.
Trying to make a JSON call and examine result but all attempts giving me undefined.

```
describe('Test Number 000001 !!!', function() {
  it('starts off OK', function() {
    expect(true).to.equal(true)
  })  
  it('can call the example api', function() {
    cy.request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  })  
  it('can call the example api and store the result', function() {
    result = cy.request('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json()) // I tried with and without then
    expect(result).to.equal(1) // will fail but once i get real response I will adjust
  })  
})
```

[image]

[image]

Update: the below passes... but doesn't actually check anything (any values used will pass)

```
    cy.request('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').
    then((response) => {
      response = JSON.stringify(response)
      var jsonData = JSON.parse(response)
      for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        expect(jsonData[i]['xuserId']).to.equal(1)
      }
    })
```

Comment: Have you confirmed what the structure of `response` actually is? I tend to add a `console.log(response)` and then a `cy.pause()` so I can examine what something like `cy.request` is actually giving me. Then run the test using `cypress open` and open the browser developer tools (since you have very few tests, you may need to add a `cy.wait(5000)` or something at the start to give you time to `F12` before it hits that test).

Comment: In particular, I'm wondering if the JSON object you're expecting is actually wrapped in `response.body`.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the same test API earlier and have got the results like below; Please have a look. I have used `response.body.` to get json values

```
it('Sample Api testing', function () {
        cy.request({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
            headers: {
                'accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
            expect(response.body.userId).to.eq(1);
            expect(response.body.id).to.eq(1);
            expect(response.body.title).to.eq('delectus aut autem');
        })
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert response object to a json string using stringify function inside the promise.

```
.then((response) => {
    response = JSON.stringify(response)
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(response)
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
     expect(jsonData[i]['userId']).eq(1)
       }
```

edit

```
expect(jsonData[i]['userId']).to.equal(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, however that is returning true regardless of whatever values I have for userId and 1 i.e. I can use 'xxxxx' and 999 and it still passes

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - not worried about downvote :), expect is always a promise itself and i guess you need to use strict equal. expect(myObj).to.equal(anotherReference)